# Remove first character of a string in Bash

Tags: bash

I need to calculate md5sum of one string (pathfile) per line in my `ls` dump, `directory_listing_file`:

```
./r/g4/f1.JPG
./r/g4/f2.JPG
./r/g4/f3.JPG
./r/g4/f4.JPG
```

But that md5sum should be calculated  without the initial dot.
I've written a simple script:

```
while read line
do
    echo $line | exec 'md5sum'
done

./g.sh < directory_listnitg.txt
```

How do I remove the first dot from each line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the field separator to the path separator and read everything except the stuff before the first slash into `$name`:

```
while IFS=/ read junk name
do
    echo $name
done < directory_listing.txt
```

Answer (score 359):

```
myString="${myString:1}"
```

Starting at character number 1 of myString (character 0 being the left-most character) return the remainder of the string.  The "s allow for spaces in the string. For more information on that aspect look at $IFS.

Comment: This answer is fastest because it is pure bash. The others run an external process for all strings. This is not be important at all if you have only a handful of strings to process, but can be important if you have a high number of strings and little work to do (on average on each string).

Comment: This is also a more general and therefore may be applied to many more cases. Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is just what I needed - `"${myString:1}"` returns the substring, but does not change the value of `myString`.

Comment: is this pipeable?

Answer (score 103):

You can pipe it to

```
cut -c2-
```

Which gives you

```
while read line
do
echo $line | cut -c2- | md5sum
done

./g.sh < directory_listnitg.txt
```

Comment: for those wondering what on earth could this `=syntax=` mean, the `-c2-` argument could be interpreted as: return characters (`-c`) starting from second one and till the end `2-`, e.g. other examples could be `-c2-5` for range or `-c3` for a single letter; to cut counting from the end, [use](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64673/144997) `rev | cut .. | rev`

Answer (score 31):

remove first n characters from a line or string

## method 1) using bash

```
 str="price: 9832.3"
 echo "${str:7}"
```

## method 2) using cut

```
 str="price: 9832.3"
 cut -c8- <<< $str
```

## method 3) using sed

```
 str="price: 9832.3"
 sed 's/^.\{7\}//' <<< $str
```

## method 4) using awk

```
 str="price: 9832.3"
 awk '{gsub(/^.{7}/,"");}1' <<< $str
```

Comment: You ended up giving the same command for cut and sed; nevertheless, very usefu!! +1

Comment: I still can't believe how ugly shell is

Comment: @Mehdi Perhaps beauty is in the eye of the beholder...

Answer (score 9):

There ia a very easy way to achieve this:

Suppose that we don't want the prefix "i-" from the variable

```sh
$ ROLE_TAG=role                                                                            
$ INSTANCE_ID=i-123456789
```

You just need to add '#'+[your_exclusion_pattern], e.g:

```sh
$ MYHOSTNAME="${ROLE_TAG}-${INSTANCE_ID#i-}"
```

```sh
$ echo $MYHOSTNAME
role-123456789
```

Answer (score 8):

Or like this

```
myString="${myString/.}"
```

Testing on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, bash 4.4.20:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.4.20(1)-release

$ myString="./r/g4/f1.JPG"
$ myString="${myString/.}"
$ echo $myString
/r/g4/f1.JPG
```

And this command will remove any first character:

```
echo ${myString/?}
```

Answer (score 7):

Different approach, using sed, which has the benefit that it can handle input that doesn't start with a dot. Also, you won't run into problems with `echo` appending a newline to the output, which will cause md5sum to report bogus result.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
     echo -n $line | sed 's/^.//' | md5sum
done < input
```

compare these:

```
$ echo "a" | md5sum
60b725f10c9c85c70d97880dfe8191b3  -

$ echo -n "a" | md5sum
0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661  -
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do the entire thing like this:

```
% sh -c `sed 's@^.\(.*\)@md5sum \1@' <./dirlist.txt`
```

Really, I'm thinking you can make this a lot more efficient, but I don't know what is generating your list. If you can `pipe` it from that, or run that command through a `heredoc` to keep its output sane, you can do this whole job streamed, probably.

**EDIT:**

OK, you say it's from an "ls dump." Well, here's something a little flexible:

```
% ls_dump() {
> sed 's@^.\(.*\)$@md5sum \1@' <<_EOF_ | sh -s
>> `ls ${@}`
>> _EOF_
> }
% ls_dump -all -args -you /would/normally/give/ls
<desired output>
```

I think this calls only a single subshell in total. It should be pretty good, but in my opinion, `find ... -exec md5sum {} ... +` is probably safer, faster, and all you need.

**EDIT2:**

OK, so now I will actually answer the question. To remove the first character of a string in any POSIX compatible shell you need only look to parameter expansion like:

```
${string#?}
```

-Mike

Comment: Great command, just found a solution for my case. I had to remove the first 3 characters of a string using the POSIX shell, and `${string#???}` worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One option that hasn't been mentioned yet is `tail`:

```sh
$ echo test | tail -c+2
est
```